# CosmoDB with Qt

Tags: qt, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Hello and I am new to developing with Qt for cross platform development. My current goal is to be able to cache data from a CosmosDB with my app that I've developed in Qt. I've had no problem setting up the CosmosDB, but I am confused at what the best way to communicate with the database is.

Do I need to create my own API to talk with the database? Are there libraries out there already do what I want?

Comment: Can you explain what are the activities you plan for with CosmosDB

Comment: @MohammadKanan Without being too specific, I intend to use it to store a list of different devices and properties that belong to them to be able query when I launch the app

Answer (score 1):

You can use either standard HTTP requests, or use SQL API.

Azure Cosmos DB exposes resources through the REST APIs that can be called by  HTTP/HTTPS requests. [How can I develop apps with the SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-introduction#develop)

Azure Cosmos DB REST API [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-resource-uri-syntax-for-rest)

Also Azure Cosmos DB offers a query language as an interface to query JSON documents. The language supports a subset of ANSI SQL grammar and adds deep integration of JavaScript object, arrays, object construction, and function invocation. Microsoft shows [exmaples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#GettingStarted)

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding conceptually what is going on with HTTP requests and maybe the SQL API as well. Are these both things that I can use agnostic of code language?

I know QT has a QNetworkAccessManager along with QNetworkRequests and replies, but it's unclear as to how I use them with the CosmosDB.

Comment: In short, you don't need _own API_, these are already offered to you, take a step a head and start with SQL using something similar to the example. [Qt SQL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtsql-index.html)

Comment: _I know QT has a QNetworkAccessManager along with QNetworkRequests and replies_ ..... see the reference I added in answer